# Bitbucket pipelines lastest Node js (at least 7.4.0)

Tags: node.js, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have an application with tests on Bitbucket and I want to run the tests everytime sombebody pushes something to the git. I've found out that new feature Bitbucket Pipelines is for that the best.

What I need?
I can't find anywhere the lastest version of Node js I can use for that.
I am using ES6 (ES2015) syntax and it fails because it doesn't know the `let, const, class, ...` keywords.

I have `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` which looks like this:

image: node:5.11.0

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
         script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
           - npm install
           - npm test
```

but it fails. What is the lastest version of node js I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a valid nodejs image.

To use version 7.4.0, add

```
image: node:7.4.0
```

in your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file

Comment: Thank you, didn't know it's that easy.

Comment: I will mark this as a correct answer but I have to wait 10 minutes

Comment: You're welcome. [Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html) are more details the options you can use.